# Tapping SVG object trigger link

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, svg

Here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript: alert('square1');">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://oyokey.hexelcolorado.com/concept/svg/square.svg"></object>
    Square 1
</a>
<br><br>
<a href="javascript: alert('square2');">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://oyokey.hexelcolorado.com/concept/svg/square2.svg"></object>
    Square 2
</a>
```

On desktop, clicking the SVG object triggers the link properly. On mobile, tapping the text works but tapping the SVG does not.

[Demo of the coding](http://oyokey.hexelcolorado.com/concept/svg.html)

Comment: What platform are you having problems with? The tap events are working fine on my iPhone. It might help if you add  `width` and `height` attributes to the object tags, or use some other embedding method like `<img>`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage It's not working for me on Chrome, Android 4.4 Kit Kat

Comment: You can't put a link round something interactive such as an `<object>` tag. You could replace it with an image tag or make the `<object>` contents non-interactive via the CSS property pointer-events: none;

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried the pointer-events: none; in CSS and that fixed it for desktop (it originally wasn't working on desktop either). However, it still doesn't work on Android 4.4 (at least for me it doesn't). I need to use <object> over <img> or using background image because I need to be able to dynamically modify the SVG via CSS.